# How to copy files to the timestamp auto generated folder?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Hello I am trying to copy all files from Documents directory to the backup directory that has a timestamp. So I have created a folder called bk$( the time stamp of the folder) and I am trying to copy files from the Documents directory to the new created folder that is unique. This will be in a crontab backing up files from documents and when the backup will kick in, it will create new directory for each backup that is uniquely identified by the folder timestamp. For some reason I cannot get the cp or cpio -mdp. Now someone had mentioned I could use $PATH variable which seems promising, if that is the solution, if someone could help me out on making it work.

```
bkdest=home/user/backup/
bksource="/home/user/Documents/"
export PATH=/$bkdest:$PATH
mkdir /"$bkdest"bk.$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
cp /"$bksource"* $PATH
```

My other approach which I have tried to use to make it work:

```
cp $bksource * ls | tail -l | $PATH
```

I could have gone with the ctime but unfortunately it does not work with the folder creation date.

This was my approach but with the latest created folder and not file

```
find $HOME -type d -daystart ctime 0
```

If someone could please help me out to copy to that new folder, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the target name in a variable:

```
bkdest=/home/user/backup
bksource=/home/user/Documents

target=${bkdest}/bk.$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
mkdir -p $target
cp ${bksource}/* ${target}/
```

Note I tidied up your use of variables a little.

Also, this won't copy subdirectories.  For that you need to use `cp -R`.  When I do backups I prefer to use `rsync`.

Comment: Oh wow thank you! I wasn't sure of the target and how it works. I've heard that the same can be accomplished using $PATH. Is it? I'm open to various ways that in this situation this could be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your approach or what exactly you want to do but here it goes.

## CP Approach

You should not use `cp` for backups, `rsync` is far more suitable for this. But if for some reason you *really* need to use `cp`, you can use the following script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BKP_DIR=/tmp/bkp
BKP_SRC=/tmp/foo
SNAPSHOT=${BKP_DIR}/$(date +%F.%H-%M-%S.%N)

mkdir -p ${SNAPSHOT}
cp -r ${BKP_SRC}/* ${SNAPSHOT}
```

## Rsync Approach

No big change here.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BKP_DIR=/tmp/bkp
BKP_SRC=/tmp/foo
SNAPSHOT=${BKP_DIR}/$(date +%F.%H-%M-%S.%N)

rsync -a ${BKP_SRC}/ ${SNAPSHOT}/
```

## Improved Rsync Approach (RECOMMENDED)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BKP_DIR=/tmp/bkp
BKP_SRC=/tmp/foo
SNAPSHOT=${BKP_DIR}/$(date +%F.%H-%M-%S.%N)
LATEST=${BKP_DIR}/latest

rsync                               \   
    --archive                       \       
    --delete                        \       
    --backup                        \       
    --backup-dir=${SNAPSHOT}        \       
    --log-file=${BKP_DIR}/rsync.log \
${BKP_SRC}/ ${LATEST}/
```

*EXPLAINING:* `--archive` plus `--delete` will make sure that `$LATEST` is a perfect copy of `$BKP_SRC`, it means that files that no longer exist in `$BKP_SRC` will be deleted from `$LATEST`. The `--archive` option also ensure that permissions and owners will be maintained, symlinks will be copied as symlinks, and more (look at `man rsync` for more information).

The `--backup` plus `--backup-dir` options will create a backup directory to put differential files. In other words, all files that were deleted or modified since last backup will be put in there, so you do not lost them as they are deleted from `$LATEST`.

`--log-file` is optional, but it is aways good to keep logs for debug purposes.

At the end you have an incremental backup.